# Displaying Array with JOptionPane

Tags: java, arrays, swing, joptionpane

First, this is a school activity, an activity that i cant solve by my own.

i'm a first year college BSIT student and this my first post.

i'm having trouble in displaying my "initialized array" in JOptionPane, i cant find the right code to display them. hope you get my question.

heres my code..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String display="";

        String size = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Your Prefered Size Of Your Array");
        int newsize = Integer.parseInt(size);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You Entered "+newsize+".");

        String array[] = new String[newsize];

        for (int a=0; a<array.length;a++)
        {
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Value For Array["+a+"].");
        }

        for (int a=0;a<array.length;a++)
        {
            display = display +array[a];
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\n"+array[display]);

    }

}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form. 3) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help. 4) What *is* your question?

Comment: You just need `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\n"+display);`

Comment: ahhmm, Im sorry, i'm not good in english and i didn't nos. 1-3, and for no. 4.

 my QUESTION is , how to display all myarrays in JOPtionPane.showMessageDialog.

Comment: but sir, i get an output "nullnull".

Comment: @user2981000 Thats because you are not saving your values to array. Refer to answer given by @ Tomas Bisciak

Comment: yes, it works.
but i want to make a new line for the next set of array.

Comment: @user2981000 I think you should think over how it can be achieved. **HINT:** You need to make minor changes in second `for` loop where you are creating string `display`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Value For Array["+a+"].");
```

shoud be

```
array[a]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Value For Array["+a+"].");
```

and then make string

```
for (int a=0;a<array.length;a++)
    {
        display+=array[a]+","
    }
```

after that just print it out :)

for new line `display+=array[a]+"\n"`

Comment: sir, iget the same output, null,null.

Comment: yes, it works. but i want to make a new line for the next set of array. thanks @Tomas Bisciak

Comment: for new line    display+=array[a]+"\n"

Comment: great! Thakn you so much guys.

i hava to go now, i have 7:30 class.

SALAMAT!!!!

Answer (score 0):

you could do that in 1 loop.

For example:

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    String display="";

    String size = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Your Prefered Size Of Your Array");
    int newsize = Integer.parseInt(size);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You Entered "+newsize+".");

    String array[] = new String[newsize];

    for (int a=0; a<array.length;a++)
    {
        array[a] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Value For Array["+a+"].");
        display = display +array[a] + "\n";
    }


    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,display);

}
```

}